# Filter spam accounts

Tags: customer-account

I've applied a captcha and have prevented the creation of any further spam accounts, but have an unknown large number of accounts to delete. Is there a way to filter accounts by length of user name (as they are all very long) or by empty fields (most of the rest of the fields are blank)?

An example 'name':

> вера, сегодня Китaйcкий Новый Гoд! и мы раздаeм купоны от 2019p вceм пoсетитeлям: https://www.google.com/#%62%74nI=381p&q=%65Bo%6EuSELO - успей получить в течение 24 часов! Для получения информации перейдите по ссылке выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these spam accounts, you can filter the name for `https://www.google.com` in your customer-grid

Comment: that gave me the idea that I could in fact filter name for `http` to catch any non-google links, of which there were numerous.